# Registering to a server in another container in Docker

Tags: docker, sockets, docker-compose

Trying to containerize an application and needing guidance.

Non docker approach, I have 2 systems. System 1 acts like a central server(repository for servers) and also has the client application running.System 2, has other example servers which register to the central server.The URL will of the central server is known and hence registration is smoothly carried out.

In dockers, I have 1 container with the central server and the client functionality
The second container, has the example server which should get registered to the container 1 server. (I tried giving localhost, 127.0.0.1:4840 as the endpoint to register (4840 is a port).

It fails.

EDIT: docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  # GUI to keep the overview, just open 127.0.0.1:9000 in your webbrowser, user: admin, password will be set during your first login. navigate to the stack overview to see all your containers
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - portainer_data:/data
  #Global Discovery Server with client
  GDS:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_GDS   
    image: opcuadiscovery_globaldiscoveryserver:latest
    ports:
      - "4840"
  # Crane servers
  Server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Server   
    image: opcuadiscovery_server:latest
  # Clients
  #Client:
  #  build:
   #   context: .
    #  dockerfile: Dockerfile_Client  
    #image: opcuadiscovery_client:latest


volumes:
  portainer_data:
```

How can I know the URL of the central server in the docker container to register smoothly.

Kindly excuse me if the question is silly. But please provide some guidance.

Regards,
Rakshan

Comment: What does this have to do with C? It's a generic container question. It's also lacking specific details.

Comment: what details are expected?

Comment: For one, making this question readable. The formatting used is a wreck.

Comment: yes ok. Formatting is taken care. More readable also I believe. Any guidance?

Comment: Are you using Docker Compose? If so you can leverage some of the auto-DNS discovery it can do. If not you need to use Docker networking to do this, for which there are a multitude of examples for running any kind of server process like MySQL or Redis.

Comment: yes i am using docker-compose. But I would not be knowing the central servers address right? When I run the whole application together

Comment: You define it with your `docker-compose` configuration file. There's a number of ways to do this, so you pick whatever works best. Look for any example with a client and server.

Comment: I think I am doing it wrong. I specify the dockerfiles for the 2 containers and give the docker-compose command. So, I would not know in hand what the IP of one container is.

Comment: It'd help to show your `docker-compose.yml` file. Edit to include in your question.

Comment: Yes, I have added it here

Comment: The service name `GDS` should be usable as a host name, within this set of containers.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this in more detail.